# How to replace webkit javascript interface by React Native Bridge

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webkit

I have a android App which uses Webkit for rendering the Web Pages and is build using Android Studio. I have Editor.html File (which is written in html, javascript and css). It uses the android webkit interface to communicate between JavaScript and the Native Code.

Now i want to use React Native Bridge to do the communication between Javascript and Native Code.

Is it possible?
If yes, how do i do the communication?

Comment: Yes you can, to communicate use EventEmitter (look at react-native docs)

Comment: Can i use the same code js code or will i have to rewrite the code of editor.html in JSX?

Comment: You can use the same js code, but not the one who are manipulating DOM element.